# Nautilus automatically browses as root

Tags: nautilus, root, sudo

I used gksudo nautilus (not through the terminal but through the 'Open With' command) for some copy & paste stuff that requires root access.

But now whenever I open the file browser (Nautilus) to access my local folder, it doesn't open normally, but opens with root access as if I had used `gksudo nautilus` again.

Only Trash is able be to opened normally without any root access.

How can I get back the normal, unprivileged behavior for nautilus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the `/home/user/.local/share/applications/` directory, in there is you users custom mime settings. One or more files will be called userapp-*SOMETHING*.desktop just delete the one causing problems - you can examine which one you need to delete by opening them with gedit.

You might have to re-login for changes to take affect but I don't think so.

Answer (score 8):

In general it might be a good idea to install `nautilus-gksu`. This package allows you to switch to root. It adds a menu entry where you can choose to work with root access.